# How to configure TimestampFormat for MicrosoftConsoleLayout

Tags: c#, parameters, nlog

I'm working on a C# application, using `NLog` for logging purposes.

I have added an `NLog.config` file to my application, containing the following layout definition for the console logs:

```
<target xsi:type="Console" name="lifetimeConsole" layout="${MicrosoftConsoleLayout}" />
```

This is ok, but I would like to add a timestamp.

According to [this webpage](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MicrosoftConsoleLayout), it is possible to add a timestamp to this layout (by default, that parameter is `null`, as mentioned on that same webpage).

How can I modify my target definition in `NLog.config` in order to add a `TimestampFormat` (preferably `${longdate}`? (I simply don't know the syntax)

Comment: Well there is a website only for NLog... https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers

Comment: @Heslacher: according to that website, I believe that the correct syntax is `<target xsi:type="Console" name="lifetimeConsole" layout="${MicrosoftConsoleLayout:TimestampFormat=${longdate}}" />`. Can you confirm this is correct?

Comment: See my example config below

Comment: I couldn't test your config because it seems it isn't compatible with my VS

Comment: @Heslacher: how do you mean?

Comment: I couldn't test `MicrosoftConsoleLayout` at all.

Answer (score 2):

`TimestampFormat` for [MicrosoftConsoleLayout](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MicrosoftConsoleLayout) can be any format accepted by `DateTime.ToString(format)`. Ex. `${MicrosoftConsoleLayout:TimestampFormat=o}` or `${MicrosoftConsoleLayout:TimestampFormat=HH\:mm\:ss}`.

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there is [nlog-project.org](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=targets) which is a very good reference.

e.g as an example for one of my configs see

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <Variable name = "UsedLogLevel" Value = "Info"/>
  <Variable name = "Logfile" Value = "Logfile"/>
  <Variable name = "LogfileFolder" Value = "${basedir}"/>
  <Variable name = "daylyLogging" Value = "1"/>
  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${var:LogfileFolder}/${when:when='${var:daylyLogging}'==1:inner=${shortdate}_}${var:Logfile}.txt" layout="${when:when='${var:daylyLogging}'==1:inner=${time}:else=${date}}|${windows-identity}|${level}|${replace:searchFor=de.inFLOWmation.paperCMD.:replaceWith=:inner=${callsite}}|${message}"/>
    <target name="logconsole" xsi:type="Console" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="de.inFLOWmation.paperCMD.*" minlevel="${var:UsedLogLevel}" writeTo="logconsole" />
    <logger name="de.inFLOWmation.paperCMD.*" minlevel="${var:UsedLogLevel}" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Where you can set the variables at the top by c# like

```
NLog.LogManager.Configuration.Variables["LogfileFolder"] = @"D:\someFolder;
NLog.LogManager.Configuration.Variables["UsedLogLevel"] =  "Debug";
NLog.LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```